# Installing custom hyphenation in Tex Live

Tags: texlive, babel, languages, hyphenation

I found a [Macedonian hyphenation definition online](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mkdtex/wikis/PageName.wiki), but I cannot find a way to install it on my Windows machine. I'm using Tex Live.

The description on the link is in Macedonian an says:

1. Unpack the archive on the same level as your TeX distribution (e.g. /usr/share)
2. Refresh the ls-r database (using the `texhash` command)

I tried these steps, but it didn't work. When I build my .tex document, I get the message:

> "No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for(babel) the language `Macedonian' into the format."

I have a `Macedonian.ldf` file already in my project, so that part works. It's just the hyphenation that I need to add.

I tried a huge amount of other ways to make it work, but I was not successful. I couldn't find any solutions online, so I have to ask you guys for help.

Comment: Windows has a bit different location where it saves its files. You can copy your files to your users `texmf` folder (usually `c:\users\#youruser\texmf`. To run the `texhash` command, open a cmd terminal and browse to your texlive bin-folder (usually `cd\texlive\2015\bin\win32` as a command does the trick. Then run `texhash`.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT Thanks, but running `texhash` doesn't seem to do anything. I tried placing the folder structure in C:\Users\{Username}\texmf\ (this did not exist before), and also in ...\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\, but nothing happens when I use `texhash` or re-build the .tex file.

Comment: Okay, as I see it, you have to copy it -- according to your link -- in your tex folder (`c:\texlive\2015\texmf-dist\tex\generic`) one file in the `babel` and one in the `hyphen` folder.

Comment: note that for pdftex you can not load hyphenation patterns into a normal tex run you need to rebuild the latex format with the patterns included.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT Thanks, I tried that already, but to no avail.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, how can I do that? What would the process be like?

Comment: see the comments in texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've already implemented all those steps, i.e. created the needed files (e.g. `loadhyph-mk.tex`, `hyph-mk.pat.txt`) and modified the three files `texlive\2013\texmf-var\tex\generic\config\language.d*`. What should I do next?

Comment: probably just run fmtutil-sys